# How to put two list view on same place in android layout in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

How to put two list view on same place in android layout .at a time one list view is visible.
i tried but even when 1st list view is invisible the second list view start from the mid of the layout ? Please tell me how i dynamically create and destroy listview so on the same point  both list views start one at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put both list views in a `FrameLayout`. That's it. The FrameLayout does no positioning of the contained views an just prints them one over the other. Just make sure, as you wrote, that at one time only of that views set to be visible.